# animation-list not animating initially

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a checkbox that should look like a green light when checked and a red blinking light when unchecked.  To do this I created a selector called connected_selector.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/green_button" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/red_button_blinking" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_button_blinking" />
</selector>
```

The green_button is simply a png and the red_button_blinking is an animation-list of pngs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_button" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_button_lit" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```

The checkbox's background is set to @drawable/connected_selector.  If the checkbox is initially unchecked, it doesn't blink, it just shows the @drawable/red_button.  However if I check the box and then uncheck it, the checkbox will animate correctly.

How can I make the animation start initially since the checkbox will be initially unchecked?  I guess I could try to start the animation manually in code, but I don't think that should be necessary.

Comment: To get around it for now I just got it to work by manually starting the animation in onWindowFocusChanged, but I shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: I have the exact same issue with a ToggleButton. All works fine with user interaction. However, it fails to start the animation initially. Moreover, I wasn't even able to activate it from code. Have you gained some more insight in the meantime?

Comment: Addendum: same issue with ImageView as well

Comment: Sorry man, I haven't.  Moreover, I haven't worked on Android in about 6 months or more, been moved to iOS.  It's a damn shame too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found an ugly, dirty hack to get around this. Note that I don't have the slightest clue *why* this happens, just a way around this. It is probably not even a generic way since different devices will have different loading times.

I execute the following workaround in `onPostResume()` to minimize the necessary delay time.

```
if(onOffStatus) {
    // SLEEP 0.5 SECONDS HERE ...
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            switcher.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_state_anim);

            // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
            AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) switcher.getBackground();
            // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
            frameAnimation.start();
        } 
    }, 500); // Actual required time will probably be dependent on device performance
}
```

It ain't pretty but I'm going with this until I find something better. Let me know if I overlooked something here.